# MS Access VBA: Advisable to change INT to LONG?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Over the last several months after release of my Access app, we have bumped into a small handful of instances where my INTEGER variables turn out to be too small for the actual data.  Happened again today when a user attempted to load a dataset containing 33850 records. The error was thrown during a dcount type operation to post the recordcount to a form.

It is clear I did not anticipate datasets as large as we occasionally see.

I correct the issues as they arise by re-defining the variables as LONG.

Would it be advisable to simply redefine all my INTEGER variables as LONG and be done with it?  I am not clear the risks/issue with such an approach.

Any guidance here?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' - the VBA Integer type is a signed 16 bit integer not a signed 32 bit one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's all you should do. While there is the potential of a performance hit, it is virtually inconsequential. There are no risks, and obviously in some situations, you need the extra capacity a LONG provides. LONG and INT are handled the same in math and conversion functions.

Note that VBA and Visual Basic (.NET) ranges for an INT are quite different. VBA is between -32,768 to 32,767, so you must change it.